# SELECT DISTINCT ON in Postgresql returns multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

When I run

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (ts) * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE clause=100 
AND ts <= '2018-04-02 15:11:18.819000' 
AND ts > '2018-04-02 15:06:18.819000' 
ORDER BY ts, version ASC;
```

I expect a single row corresponding to the largest `ts` that meets the condition, with ties being broken by taking the lowest `version`.

The query returns

```
         ts                     version
'2018-04-02 15:07:04.828'   ...   1
'2018-04-02 15:07:05.706'   ...   1
```

I don't understand why two non-distinct `ts` are being returned. Is there a similar query that will return the desired result?

Comment: The 2 rows are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Distinct on` returns one row for each combination of the keys following the clause.  In this case, each `ts` would appear once.  Which one?  That is determined by the `order by`.  The keys following the `distinct on` keys determine the first, so that would be the lowest version number.

Your query appears to be producing reasonable results.

If you want one row in the result set with the largest `ts`, then use `order by` and `limit`/`fetch first 1 row only`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE clause = 100 AND
      ts <= '2018-04-02 15:11:18.819000' AND
      ts > '2018-04-02 15:06:18.819000' 
ORDER BY ts DESC, version ASC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note the `ts DESC` in the `ORDER BY`, to get the most recent value of `ts`.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I'd gotten the idea that distinct on is supposed to only return one row.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, do you want to get `version` and last `ts`

In your case it's better to use no `DISTINCT` but `GROUP BY`

For example this code can solve your problem:

```
SELECT max(ts), version 
FROM tbl 
WHERE clause=100 
  AND ts <= '2018-04-02 15:11:18.819000' 
  AND ts > '2018-04-02 15:06:18.819000' 
GROUP BY version;
```